# Facebook like button embed count - inconsistent

Tags: facebook

Why is it that the facebook like counter that is linked to website is so inconsistent.

For example i have had an blog post with a 1000 likes and the next day it is only showing 9 likes on the counter

Why does this happen and is anyone else experiencing this problem

Answer (score 1):

Is your blog in blogger, with a blogspot address?   If so, then country-code redirection might be involved.

(It could also be that people have gone back and unliked your post - but it's unlikely that 1000 people did this, unless you've done something to really upset them.)